# Scheduling tasks in PHP without cron

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django

Is it possible to schedule a task with PHP? like, I want to choose a date with the jQuery datepicker, and submit it. When that date equals today's date, an email will be sent for example (or any other PHP script). The date will be different depending on the user, also, every user can have a number of scheduled tasks to run.

**EDIT**

The OS is Linux, and the website is hosted on godaddy.com 
Also, it's the end users who will choose when to run these tasks, so they can use command lines for that.

**EDIT**

Any Ruby on Rails or Django solutions are welcomed as well.

Comment: BTW, why is it tagged ruby-on-rails and django?

Comment: oh damn, I thought I already said that any RoR or Django solutions are welcomed ! gonna edit that now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Unix server, try `at`.

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/at/

It works in a similar way to cron, in that it's totally separate from PHP, and you need to shell_exec() an external command. However, it has a simple command-line interface. Like cron jobs, `at` jobs survive reboots.

If you use `at` you'll have to write a separate script to perform the task you want scheduled.

Example:

```
shell_exec("echo 'php script.php' | at -t 201208011234.56");
```

Will run script.php on August 1st, 2012 at 12:34:56.

Answer (score 1):

You need some process in the server side to run the task at the scheduled time.

A popular approach is to store the task information in some database and have a cron job checking the task queue from time to time - it is very reliable and safe.

It is impossible to give a better answer without more information about the environment where it will be deployed. For example:

- target OS
- hosting type (dedicated, shared, cloud)
- do you have administrator privileges?
- is it exposed to the internet?

Most likely you will not be able to do that in a shared hosting environment, anyway, but I must say that having a website calling shell_exec is not very wise from a security standpoint, so I would avoid that if the site is exposed to the Internet.

A good hosting provider should have some kind of background task scheduler available, even if it is not crontab. If your hosting provider hasn't, trying to pull some stunt to fill the gap probably is a bad idea.

[update]

> As I said in the edited part of the original post, I'm hosting it on godaddy.com, and I can't let the clients run these command lines etc. Is there a solution with other languages too?

I'm not hosting at godaddy anymore but they used to have a "Cron Manager" at their control panel. I think the correct goDaddy cron setup is

```
/usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://yoursite.com/cron.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

at the Command Option in the Cron Manager. This "cron.php" will check the task queue to see if there are any email to send (the task queue being a simple table in your database where you will record any task scheduled by your customers).

Comment: As I said in the edited part of the original post, I'm hosting it on godaddy.com, and I can't let the clients run these command lines etc. Is there a solution with other languages too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without cron by simply adding a check into the main index page, or a standard include file - but that's only for when you really can't get access to cron (e.g. shared hosting). In this check you'd grab the list of outstanding actions and execute them, possibly by using

```
if (time_since_last_run > 5*60) // minutes
    shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/check-tasks.php &");
```

The best solution is to use cron to launch a PHP script that will check for scheduled items within your system and execute them. You can either do this via wget or directly via calling PHP.

One shared hosting site that I have is externally scheduled from another of my servers via cron and wget http://othersite.example.com.

example crontab entry:

```
0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://othersite.example.com/cron.php
```